# node.js - function w/ mysql query not working

Tags: node.js

this is the main

```
9.js
```

i am sending the "connection" details to
`3.js` so it can be used in the function named 'oo'

```
var http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : '------------',
    user     : '2',
    password : '--------------',
    database : '1',
});

connection.connect();
var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'});
    var oo = require('/3.js');
    var ee = oo(connection);
    res.end(ee);
}).listen(80);
```

this is the `3.js`

```
function oo(connection) {

    var ss = 'SELECT * FROM 1_accounts order by ac_nu asc limit 5';
    connection.query(ss, function(err,res,fields){
    bb = JSON.stringify(res);
    });
    return bb;
}
module.exports = oo;
```

let's run :

```
root@11669:/# node 9.js
/3.js:7
    return bb;
           ^

ReferenceError: bb is not defined
    at oo (/3.js:7:9)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/9.js:20:11)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:528:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:88:23)
root@11669:/#
```

it claims "bb" is not defined.
but it is defined in the function.

i prefer not adding any "callback" things. trying to figure out the simplest way to get "bb" perhaps via "return" like regular normal function just like in php and so on..

Comment: In your 9.js you import `oo` with the name `aa`, then try to use `oo`. You may want to start by fixing that.

Comment: Where is bb defined in 3.js? And mysql is asynchronous, so you will need a callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong.

For a start `bb` is not declared in the scope it is used. you are returning something that was never declared.

Not only that but `bb`was not even declared. Before (or the first time) you use it you should declare it with var.

However, the main problem here is that you are returning before you even get the query result. DB means I/O which could take some time. You should provide a callback to use when the result is calculated. e.g.

```
function oo(connection, callback) {

    var ss = 'SELECT * FROM 1_accounts order by ac_nu asc limit 5';
    connection.query(ss, function(err,res,fields){
        var bb = JSON.stringify(res);

        // in node.js it is conventional to reserve the first 
        // argument of a callback for errors.
        callback(null, bb);
    });
}
module.exports = oo
```

then in your client code:

```
connection.connect();
var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'});
    var oo = require('/3.js');
    oo(connection, function (e, result) {
        res.end(result);
    });

}).listen(80);
```